# How to fix out of memory issue in tomcat8

Tags: java, out-of-memory, tomcat8, geoserver

I am trying to get all features as json from WFS request as below

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/DATA/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=DATA:species&outputFormat=application/json
```

I am getting out of memory error  as

```
<ServiceExceptionReport xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/OGC-exception.xsd">
<ServiceException>
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException java.io.IOException null     Ran out of memory retrieving query results. Java heap space
</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

How to fix this memory issue or increase the memory in tomcat8?

Comment: Configuring tomcat memory settings depends on operating system and how you start it. Please provide more info.

Comment: AM using Ubuntu15.04 and am starting as service. sudo service tomcat8 start.

Answer (score 5):

If you installed it properly, the way to configure tomcat 8 in ubuntu is by editing `/etc/default/tomcat8`. E.g., to have a 2048MB heap, change `JAVA_OPTS` to include `-Xmx2048m`:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx2048m"
```

Comment: I did the above changes. But no luck. Issue remains same.

Comment: Did you change/add any other file that was suggested in the other answers here (e.g. setenv.sh)? In that case, please undo that change first. If message still persists, try increasing memory even more.

Comment: So you're saying that the memory error is gone and replaced by a new problem? In that case you should finish this thread by marking the answer as correct and start a new thread for the new problem (obviously searching for a solution yourself first :))

Comment: Sorry the error still persists.

Comment: How are you starting the tomcat server? Is it properly installed as a service so that you can do `sudo service tomcat8 start/stop`?

Comment: Yes its installed as service and am using sudo service tomcat8 to start.

Comment: First of all, verify that tomcat is running using the specified memory parameters: `ps -ef | grep tomcat`. If it is indeed running with -Xmx4096m I suspect something is seriously wrong with the web application you're running. If not, something is still wrong in your other configuration files.

Comment: What is the difference between modifying tomcat8 file and creating the env.sh with parameters under tomcat8/bin/  path?

Comment: It's just the standard way of configuring things in ubuntu; system services are typically configured under /etc; I guess whatever changes you do under /tomcat8/bin may be overwritten by an automatic service update (apt-get dist-upgrade). This may or may not be true in this particular case, but the default configuration standard should be followed nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file under Tomcat home \bin directory if windows then
      setenv.bat
and if linux/unix then setenv.sh
and write below memory configuration into file

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xms512m"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xmx8192m" export        CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
```

please refer this link

http://crunchify.com/how-to-change-jvm-heap-setting-xms-xmx-of-tomcat/

Comment: I tried as mentioned in the link. Am getting the below error Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat8
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat8
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat8/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat8/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx512MB
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: -Xmx512m, not -Xmx512mb

Comment: Also, tomcat is configured using /etc/default/tomcat8 on ubuntu. See separate answer.